# Firebase config file dynamic import at Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js

firebaseInit.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const FirebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
};

firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

what did i try;

```
var data = async function getConfig() {
  var x= await fetch('/someurl')
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      return console.log(err);
    });
  return x;
};

firebase.initializeApp(getConfig());

export default firebase;
```

i can get external config file but it is not exporting..................................

Answer (score 0):

Export a promise-returning function...

```
// firebaseInit.js
import firebase from "firebase/app";

export default function() {
  return fetch('/someurl').then(res => {
    firebase.initializeApp(res.json());
    return firebase
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  });
};
```

Await it in the importing module...

```
import firebasePromise from 'firebaseInit.js'
let firebase;

async someFunction() {
  firebase = firebase || await firebasePromise();
  // use firebase
}
```

Comment: Whoops. I just realized that initializeApp doesn't return the firebase instance. Edited. (also, on SO, when "it doesn't work", add clues from console.log)